# Appending and slicing vectors in Cython

Tags: python, c++, vector, cython, cythonize

I've been using C++ vectors in Cython a fair bit lately and its been working rather well. However, I was wondering if there was an efficient way to get slices from vectors via Cython and also how I can use those vector slices to extend another vector? For example, if I do something like this:

```
cdef vector[int] v1, v2
v1.push_back(11)
v1.push_back(12)
v1.push_back(13)
v2.push_back(v1[0])
```

How would I extend vector v2 with the entire contents of v1 in one pass like I could in C++ and how could I take the elements from a subsetted slice from v1?

Comment: C++ vectos don't really use slices I think? They use iterators. In any case the interface in Cython doesn't add anything to the C++ interface, so if you know how to do it in C++ then try to translate that.

Comment: Typed memoryviews work with C arrays, but I don't see any discussion of their use with C++ vectors.

Comment: @hpaulj It should work - the memory is guaranteed to to be contiguous so you could just get a pointer to the first element and use it as an array. The thing to be wary of is that anything that can resize the vector can invalidate the pointer, so you'd have to be careful there.